# Load/Prepend HTML from PHP file into div on button click using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, prepend

I want to load/prepend HTML from PHP file into div on button click using Jquery. How can I go about doing this since `.load` was deprecated? I need to load the HTML that is nested within the PHP file and prepend it to the top of a div whenever a button is clicked.

Comment: You might get an answer if you provided what you have tried, your code, something....

Comment: I don't know *exactly* what you are asking, as you are very *unclear*. Are you looking for something like `ajax` functionality? But then again, I don't really understand. Because as far as I can see in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/) it still works? Maybe that's just me though.

Comment: Load as a means to load content into a selector is not deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("selector").load(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Is depreciated. You should now use

```
$("selector").on("load", function() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP is looking for, as the title says he wants to load something from a file. I believe he's talking about the *"new"* .load() function. I could be wrong though....